# Select rows of a listbox based on an input column value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an issue with a piece of code regarding a listbox. The idea is that the user can write a searchable value on a textbox and click a button, which then searches the value from the seventh column of the listbox - if the value is found, then that row is selected. I've tried several versions but none of the rows ever get selected.

```
Dim strSearch As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long
strSearch = txtSearch
With Me.lstTest
    For lngRow = 0 To lstTest.ListCount - 1
        If (Me.lstTest.Column(6, lngRow)) = strSearch Then
            lstTest.Selected(lngRow) = True
        Else
            lstTest.Selected(lngRow) = False
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

edited

take advantage of the `With Me.lstTest` statement and reach all members of your list box starting frome there

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strSearch As Variant
    Dim lngRow As Long
    strSearch = Me.txtSearch

    With Me.lstTest
        For lngRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If (.Column(6, lngRow)) = strSearch Then
                .Selected(lngRow) = True
            Else
                .Selected(lngRow) = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! However, I get a compile error message from the .List method: "Method or data member not found"? Am I missing a reference of some sort?

Comment: Sorry, I was using Excel ListBox properties. See edited answer with Access ListBox property usage